# Broken image in Penalty Box blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, blog

Just noticed this in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) blog post:

> [image]

Clicking it still leads to the proper image hosted on flickr.

The original image, found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150222133034/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box) is:

[image]

Can it please be added back?

Comment: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/203) for this.

Comment: @Adam still not published, any estimation when it will be done so I can check?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's up now.

Comment: Cheers @Adam, had to hard refresh to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this has been [merged](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/692dc1531f50042962ca1030706f42fc83b61c1c) into the blog's [github repository](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog), so the image should return the next time it is published.

Comment: Cool, I should really stop being lazy and start doing those things myself, though never imagined the contents of the blog are static and not taken from a database...